# Is there a way to make NetBeans hide specific files/folders?

Tags: netbeans, joomla

I'm working on a joomla project and for debugging/type hinting/auto-complete have my whole joomla install as a project. Is there a way I can hide the folders I don't need in file or project view?

Ideally I would have a project that scans all of the folders but simply displays this:

- administrator

  - components

    - com_myproject

      - (display all files under this)
- components

  - com_myproject

    - (display all files under this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do it with NetBeans like this.

However, you can do it little differently... this is going to be component development.
Basically for every custom component you will need to have a separate project.

Create project with folder structure like Joomla

```
|
|-administrator
  |-componnets
    |-my_component
|
|-componnets
  |-my_component
```

After this step, right click the **project** and go into **properties**. In the properties go to **PHP Include Path**, map path to Joomla directory, this is what is going to give you autocomplete feature for Joomla code.

Also, to improve auto-complete for Joomla, go to `Tools->Properteis->Editor->Code Copletion`
Select PHP from language drop down.
Check **Also Non-Static methods after ::**, this will give your auto-complete for methods like `JFactory::getDBO()`, etc...

Obviously it makes it hard to test right now, because component is not inside of Joomla... and copying it manually makes it a hassle. Go to project properties (right click `project->properties`) and enabled "copy files from Sources Folder to another location" and math the path. NetBeans will no allow you to setup copy into existing directory, workaround is simple.

1. Setup copy support into temp direcotry `/tmp`
2. In NetBeans windows, go to Files of your component project
3. Expand the `nbproject` node
4. Open `project.properties`
5. Manually modify the copy path

If you want something more advanced and runt test's, you can use Ant and create `build.xml` files. Read more about it on [Sun's blog about NetBeans PHP and Ant](http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/ant_support_on_php_projects).

Answer (score 15):

You can hide any directories you'd like in Netbeans 6.9.1. Right click on the project, select properties, and select the "Ignored Folders" category. In this section you can add all the directories you don't want to see.

Comment: Hi, @KristianLunde I am using NetBeans IDE 8.1 and there is no such feature that I am able to see. Can you please check and help me with this? And my project is a Java Application.
Thanks.

Comment: @VibhavChaddha hey, sorry I haven't used Netbeans since 2012. I don't know how this is done in newer versions of Netbeans.

Comment: @KristianLunde Okay. Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: This worked for me on NetBeans 8.2. Goto File->Project Properties. In the box on the left, about half way down is the 'Ignore Folders' option. Click 'Add Folders and an option box will popup with folders from your project that can be ignored.

Comment: can we ignore files with specific extension? like I dont wanna see `*.pyc` files in my project view

Comment: @Umair, Netbeans -> Preferences -> Miscellaneous gives you a regexp **Ignore Files Pattern** field. I added `|^.*\.class$` to the end of the default pattern, for example, to hide class files (generated by tool outside Netbeans).

Answer (score 0):

Heres a video that will help u to do the same using netbeans IDE. Keeping yout component file into a seperate directory and do the development making full use of IDE features using the Apache ANt build procedures.

The Ant build file.
http://docs.joomla.org/Building_Joomla_Extensions_with_Apache_Ant
The video to help you setup netbeans for component development.
http://www.vimeo.com/13167176